# Plesk Panel Email HIPAA Compliance

Tags: email, cpanel, plesk, parallels, hipaa

We are looking to create a HIPAA compliant email server using a plesk panel server. Is it possible to create a HIPAA compliant email server with this?

Comment: This might be off-topic unless you can update your question to something more specific and programming-related.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible with Plesk panel server using TLS encryption with Postfix SMTP mail server.

Comment: Do you know of all the HIPAA requirements for email servers? I can't find anything on google I've been looking for a week.